# AWS Cloudformation condition on List

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

We have a map which list all instance type with EBSOpt (Ebs-optimized supported) Flag

e.g

```
  "p2.16xlarge" : {
    "EBSOpt" : "True"
  },
```

The problem here is we have to update this map whenever new instance type arrives. But all new instance types are Ebs optimized AMI hence I plan to have revise this logic to have AWSInstanceTypesWhichDoesnotSupportEBSOpt :[List of not supported instances ] but I am not clear on how to achieve this condition as there is no enough primitives to support contains in a list. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what are you trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a list:

```
Conditions:
  isEBSOptimizable: !Not [!Equals [!Select [0, !Split [".", !Ref InstanceType]], "t2"]]
```

later:

```
      EbsOptimized: !If [isEBSOptimizable, 'true', 'false']
```